# How to show make a hidden form visible in javafx

Tags: java, javafx

I have an application that is designed to be a sandwich shop system and I have a main menu form that is my main class i.e. this class holds my main class and is the first form to open when the application is executed.

[image]

When I click on the create new standard order button I have it so it will display a menu of items to chose from. I have this code behind the create new standard order button so it will hide the first window and display the next window.

```
btnStdOrder.setOnAction(e -> { 
    ((Node)e.getSource()).getScene().getWindow().hide();
    NewOrderPopUp.Display();  
});
```

However, how do I go back to this first window? I have tried using the same code as above but because the first form holds my main and start methods I cant recall them again using the above method (or maybe I can I just don't know how to do it). Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you NewOrderPopUp.Display() ends with showandwait() you should use ((Node)e.getSource()).getScene().getWindow().show(); after NewOrderPopUp.Display();

Comment: @SedrickJefferson so the code I have above is behind the New standard Order button to display the New order screen (which is called the newOrderPopUp). What I want to try and do is to return back to the original menu class. For example I have tried to use this code `btnStdOrder.setOnAction(e -> { 

            ((Node)e.getSource()).getScene().getWindow().hide();

            SandwichShopSystem().show();  
        });` but this doesnt make the first menu show again after I have hidden it.

Comment: When do you want to go back to the previous window? On what action do you want to perform the Task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your popUpDisplay method ends with showAndWait(), you can try this:

```
((Stage)((Node)e.getSource()).getScene().getWindow()).hide();
NewOrderPopUp.Display();  
((Stage)((Node)e.getSource()).getScene().getWindow()).show();
```

I created a sample app that shows this behavior in action.

> Main

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 *
 * @author blj0011
 */
public class JavaFXApplication53 extends Application
{

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception
    {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("FXMLDocument.fxml"));

        Scene scene = new Scene(root);

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

> Controller - MainScene

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.logging.*;
import javafx.fxml.*;
import javafx.scene.*;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.stage.*;

/**
 *
 * @author blj0011
 */
public class FXMLDocumentController implements Initializable
{    
    @FXML private Button btnMain;  

    Stage window;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb)
    {

        // TODO
        btnMain.setOnAction(e -> {
            ((Stage)((Node)e.getSource()).getScene().getWindow()).hide();           
            popUpDisplay();
            ((Stage)((Node)e.getSource()).getScene().getWindow()).show();

        });
    }    

    public void popUpDisplay()
    {
        try
        {
            FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("SceneTwo.fxml"));
            Parent root1 = (Parent) fxmlLoader.load();
            Stage stage = new Stage();
            stage.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
            //stage.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);
            stage.setTitle("PopUp");
            stage.setScene(new Scene(root1));
            stage.showAndWait();
        }
        catch (IOException ex)
        {
            Logger.getLogger(FXMLDocumentController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

}
```

> FXML - Main Scene

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>

<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" maxHeight="300.0" maxWidth="300.0" minHeight="300.0" minWidth="300.0" prefHeight="300.0" prefWidth="300.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.111" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="javafxapplication53.FXMLDocumentController">
   <children>
      <Button fx:id="btnMain" layoutX="124.0" layoutY="248.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Button" />
      <Label layoutX="99.0" layoutY="135.0" text="Main Scene">
         <font>
            <Font size="20.0" />
         </font>
      </Label>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

> Controller - PopUp

```
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.fxml.*;
import javafx.scene.*;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.stage.*;

/**
 * FXML Controller class
 *
 * @author blj0011
 */
public class SceneTwoController implements Initializable
{
    @FXML Button btnClosePopup;    

    /**
     * Initializes the controller class.
     * @param url
     * @param rb
     */
    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb)
    {
        // TODO
        btnClosePopup.setOnAction(e -> {
            ((Stage)(((Button)e.getSource()).getScene().getWindow())).close();           
        });
    }    

}
```

> FXML - PopUp

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>


<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.111" fx:controller="javafxapplication53.SceneTwoController">
   <children>
      <Label layoutX="257.0" layoutY="155.0" text="Popup">
         <font>
            <Font size="30.0" />
         </font>
      </Label>
      <Button fx:id="btnClosePopup" layoutX="259.0" layoutY="353.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Close Popup" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Comment: That worked perfectly, thank you so much for your help.