# Show and Hide Main Stage in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

By default, when all windows are closed in JavaFX, the app terminates. However, I've used `Platform.setImplicistExit(false)` to let the app stays. Now, how would I show the app when the app is activated? Is there any `activate` event listener that I can listen to when the app is activated from the Mac Dock Bar?

```
@Override
public void start(final Stage stage) throws Exception {
    stage.setTitle("Hello World");

    stage.setScene(
            createScene(
                    loadMainPane()
            )
    );

    stage.show();

    Platform.setImplicitExit(false);
    stage.setResizable(false);
}
```

Or is there an event listen to listen when the system close button is clicked so I can hide the stage `stage.close()` and the app will show when is activated?

Comment: So what you want to do is hold the app active after it is closed then when someone tries to open it again you just show the stage again? If so what kind of app is this and why is it important to keep it in RAM for so long? The second part is just wondering out of curiosity.

Comment: Assume that I have an app that has two windows. The first window is login where the user needs to be logged in and the second one is a job window. When the user logged in, the second window will appear and I don't want to show the login window again until the user press `command+q`. Closing the app using the system close button will simply hide the window and once the user activate the app from the dock bar, the app will just show. I hope you get the point

Comment: This may be similar to what you are asking: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42953730/how-to-show-make-a-hidden-form-visible-in-javafx/42956021#42956021

Comment: The link you've shared is using a button to hide and show stage, not using the system close button, nor the system activates event listener. I'm looking for an event listener that I can listen to when the app is activated.

Comment: You can use one stage and change between two different Layouts , for example you have one `Stage|Window` , one `Layout(for example GridPane)` for the Login and one `Layout(example BorderPane)` for the JobScreen , when user is done with Login and pressed Enter the `Login Screen` disappears with a fade animation and `JobScreen` which is a `BorderPane` for example appears . All work nicely and with animations :) . You can combine them both in a StackPane and use a Flip Animation ...

Answer (score 3):

See if this code is of any use. This minimises the stage upon close request instead of turning off implicit exit. You still need a way to properly close this without task manager, but this seems like what you want. If it does not just comment below.

```
package minimalist;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Stack_Overflow extends Application{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        TextArea text = new TextArea();
        text.setText("Hello World!");
        StackPane stack = new StackPane();
        stack.getChildren().add(text);
        Scene scene = new Scene(stack);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.setOnCloseRequest(e -> {
            e.consume();
            primaryStage.setIconified(true);
        });
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work. It first minimized the application and then the application gets closed. For your convenience, I'm using this little window management framework here: https://gist.github.com/jewelsea/6460130

Comment: Ah sorry I know exactly the issue. Check the edited answer.

Comment: Thank you. However, this minimizes the app instead of hiding it but which does the job in a way. This also makes a new issue to close the app completely even when you press the `command + q`